# How to change class back after onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a spoiler-tag script where the user clicks on spoiler text, the text will either blank out or change font-color depending on the class assigned to it. I'm rather a noob at Javascript.

My script only works when I click on the spoilered text when it is blank- so when I have already clicked on it, I can't reclick to change it back.

Here is the code that works:

```
// Hide Spoiler Individually
var singleHidden = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");

var hideMe = function () {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("hidden");
    this.className = "show";
};

for (var i = 0; i < singleHidden.length; i++) {
    singleHidden[i].addEventListener("click", hideMe, false)
};
```

Here's a link on jsfiddle. 
https://jsfiddle.net/o94c00hb/

Comment: I'd recommend using jquery, it has classes `addClass`, `removeClass`, and `toggleClass` which are really handy

Comment: I'd recommend not using jQuery unless there is more you need it for or it fills some other dependency.  If all you need to do is add or remove classes, JavaScript [supports this natively](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for modern browsers with functions like `classList.add()`, `classList.remove()`, and `classList.toggle()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var hideMe = function() {

   if(this.className == "hidden")
        this.className = "show"
    else
        this.className = "hidden"
};
```

Comment: It works! May I ask, how "this" works? I've found it confusing to use in JS.

Comment: It is a simple if/else conditional that toggles the `className`. As other people have posted in other answers; it is much better to use a library like JQuery, rather than writing raw JS. JQuery will handle all cross-browser incompatibilities of which frequently arise when using raw JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not opposed to using jquery i would do something like this:

```
$('.hidden').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('show');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o94c00hb/1/)